# Avoiding Lookbehind in Postgres

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, split, lookbehind

In a Postgres query I wrote, I'm trying to find an empty char between a digit and a char.

The Raw-Data looks pretty similar to this:

```
"X  1111-11-112222-22-22YY 3333-33-334444-44-44ZZZ5555-55-556666-66-66AAA7777-77-778888-88-88B  9999-99-991111-11-11"
```

I would like to split this into following table:

```
X  1111-11-112222-22-22
YY 3333-33-334444-44-44
ZZZ5555-55-556666-66-66
AAA7777-77-778888-88-88
B  9999-99-991111-11-11
```

So, normally i would do this by defining the Regex `(?<\d)(?=[A-z])` which is giving me the empty char between the chars and digits, but Postgres doesn't support lookbehinds.

Anyone an idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: first, didn't think about the second, sry.

Answer (score 1):

```
 (\w+\s*[\d-]+)
```

This will give all the groups.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nW8dX7/1

Comment: So if i understand it right, you're extracting the blocks of XXX1111-11-112222-22-22 ?

Comment: Ok, because the actual Data consists of this type of blocks, seperated by either 10 or 13 (or, if combined, 23) blanks, which are extracted with this too. I've tried a non-greed verision, but I'm still stuck withe the blanks. Any idea?

Comment: (\w+\s*[\d-]+)\s* Try this.

Comment: Still leaves the blanks, even with the non-greedy version.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/nW8dX7/3 .have a look at this.dont know why yours is not working

Comment: I think the problem is, that the expression is matching the blocks incl. spaces and excl. (if you roll over the text it highlights both versions).

Comment: You have to extract groups.Dont match the while thing.

Comment: The problem is, that i want to change all of this "blank-blocks" to pipes and the above discussed blocks as well.

Comment: That has to be done by re.replace or some other function.It would require another regex.

Comment: I'm open for that. I've now tried replacing all the space-blocks having \s{3,} (so the information-blocks don't get cutted). But 
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(mystring, '(\w+\s*[\d-]+?)','|','g'),'\s{3,}','|','g')
only returns Pipes (meaning the info-blocks self are getting replaced by |, which i don't want)

Comment: Use "(\w+\s*[\d-]+)\s*" and replace by "\1|"

Comment: replace the first group which you match inside ()

Comment: Oh, understood. This even gives me nearly the desired output, except, that there are a lot of blank lines in between. Any way to work around this with the RegEx, or do I have to manualy clear them?

Comment: If the answer is correct with blank lines its better to remove separately or else we will have to check input and make regex again :).Removing blank lines should be easy.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for you help and patience :D (I would vote you up, but my reputation won't let me :/ )

Comment: I did the upvote for ya, I see @vks all the time when I'm browsing regex questions.

Comment: thanx a lot :P the irony is i cant ask anything........my question asking thing is locked. :(

Answer (score 0):

I would do a replace with a character you can then later split on. I'm not familiar with psql but something like:

```
split('~', replace(value, '\d(?=[A-z])', '$0~'))
```

Comment: This is what I'm already doing, still it inserts the char right in front of the digit, which transfers it into the next block

Comment: Could you post that code? That seems odd as this snippet explicitly tells the replace to place the `~` _after_ the $0.